# Why is the Table footer not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to total the columns in a jquery datatable but the table footer is not appearing

The Totals Appear in the console and the totals changed on filter or search.

But the table has no footer tag after init

I'm not sure if the table initialization is called before footerCallback

The Table works fine and the totals are calculated but I think it all happens before the table is initialized. Is this correct

If I'm correct what changes are required?

```
 var table = $('#resultstable').DataTable( 
 {
 fixedHeader: {
    footer: true,
        footerOffset: 40
           },
           "paging": false,
           "info":false,
           "stateSaving":true,
           "searching":true,
           "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
           data:tabledata,
           columnsDef:[
           {
               "targets":[2],
                ClassName:"sum"
           }],
           columns:[
                    {
                        className:'details-control',
                        orderable:false,
                        data:null,
                        defaultContent: '',

                     },
                     {                       
                        orderable:true,
                        className:"packName",
                        title:"Name : "
                     },
                     {
                        className:'sum',
                        orderable:true,
                        title:"Total : ",
                     },
                     {
                        className:'sum',
                        title:"Passed : ",
                        orderable:true,

                     },
                     {
                        className:'sum',
                        title:"Failed ",
                        orderable:true,
                     },
                     {
                        className:'sum',
                        title:"New Failures ",
                       'orderable':true
                     }
                       ],
                     "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex )
                     {
                      $(nRow).attr('value', aData[(aData.length-1)]);
                     },
                     "initComplete": function(settings, json)
                     {

                     },
            "footerCallback":function(row, data, start, end,display)
            {
                var api = this.api();
                var cols = api.columns('.sum',{search:'applied'}); 
                cols.every(function(){
                       var sum = this
                           .data()
                           .reduce(function(a,b){
                           var x = parseFloat(a) || 0;
                           var y = parseFloat(b) || 0;
                           return x + y;
                       },0);
                       console.log(sum); 
                       $(this.footer()).html(sum);

                       });
                       }
  } );
```

Comment: `$(this.footer()).html(sum);` - looks like you're replacing the whole `<tfoot>` with a `float`.

Comment: Examples use `$(row).find('th').eq(0).html(sum)` but you'd have to find the correct col as you filter them.  See: https://datatables.net/reference/option/footerCallback

Comment: Solved this by adding a html table to the page  
                <table id='resultstable' class = 'table table-hover table-bordered' > 
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

    </table>

Comment: search the page for word 'tfoot', see if any css the attribute display:none is given.